# Rails route skips action and directly renders view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a namespaced controller (Interviews)

```
  namespace :recruitment do
    resources :interviews 
  end
```

I created a route (outside of the namespace)

```
get "myinterviews", to: "recruitment/interviews#my", as: :myinterviews
```

SO that /myinterviews shows the user his own interviews
Whereas rails seems to find the right view, it totally skips the controller action

```
def my
    puts "Hi there"
    exit
    @recruitment_interviews=current_user.interviews
    puts @recruitment_interviews.inspect
end
```

This is ofcourse inside Recruitments::InterviewController.
The view(recruitment/interviews#my) is rendered (it results in an error since recruitment_interviews is not found
Here's the process log:

```
Started GET "/myinterviews" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-03 18:54:48 +0530
Processing by Recruitment::InterviewsController#my as HTML
  Rendered recruitment/interviews/my.html.slim within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 2  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.slim (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 197.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: show the error stack please..

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `puts` will print directly into the `rails s` process log.

Comment: do server logs tell you the routes is heading to your expected controller/action? maybe one other takes precedence

Comment: @fylooi Yes. I just checked, and you are right. Why I didn't know this, I have no idea.. I always use `logger.info`.. but now I will use `puts`... :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit If the action was called, it would do something. I am checking the process logs. There is nothing. Exit is not doing anything either. Even random stuff asfsafa to throw syntax error doesnt work

Comment: @apneadiving Edited with the process log

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Yes, `puts` story I just got to know exist... Then you need to show us the rails process log.. there from we can get clue..

Comment: Please post the controller source code.

Comment: the controller is under `app/controllers/recruitment` directory ?

Comment: can you run this command: bundle exec rake routes | grep 'myinterviews' and update your question what your route says ?

Comment: Okay. My bad. It seems I had defined it inside another action. Rails couldn't find the action, so it rendered the view directly. Strange. I used to think route mapping would always look for the action, and if not found it would throw an exception, but it seems if the view exists, but the action doesn;t, it will render the view

Comment: yup, no action is required